# Getting JavaScript to work in IE or Edge (Win 10 build)

Tags: javascript

I am creating a web site for fellow retirees. One page displays some pdfs (works fine in Moz & Chrome) which the user can select pdfs of different sort orders but doesn't work in Edge or IE.

(calling code)

```
    <p id="test" onclick="fnByDay()"><a href="#">Sorted by Day</a></p>
    <p id="rest" onclick="fnByType()"><a href="#">Sorted by Type</a>

    <div id="courseList">     
    <script> 
    function fnByDay(){ 
        document.getElementById("CoursesPdf").data="coursesByDay.pdf";
   }                         

   function fnByType(){
       document.getElementById("CoursesPdf").data="coursesByType.pdf"; 
    }                     

    </script>                                                 

    <object id="CoursesPdf" data="_pdf/coursesByDay.pdf" width="1080"     height="900"></object>                  

    </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: try setting [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) instead of `data` , so for example `function fnByDay(){ document.getElementById("CoursesPdf").dataset="coursesByDay.pdf"; }`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - didn't work.

Comment: @robin, please explain what "doesn't work".  Do you see any messages in the javascript console?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome natively support displaying PDF's, IE does not, as for Edge, I thought it did so am a little suprised this doesn't work in Edge - you may need to look at using [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) for at least IE.

Comment: @Jaromada  I was assuming that it was a script problem.  From what you say it could be a MS problem.  I've tried this in both Edge & IE and the code does not run.  I'm new at this game so things like console are not my first port of call though it sounds as if it should be.  I'm learning.

Comment: @Grisha.  Sorry but I haven't looked at console.  Nothing worked so I assumed (bad mistake!) that it was the code causing the problem.  Will go and investigate Console.

Comment: #Grisha The console states that the functions (fnByDay() and fnByType()) are undefined.  I am having trouble with understanding how to define them.

Comment: @Jaromanda.  I am using pdf.js with excellent results for all windows browsers.  thanks for the tip.